# Is there a way to remotely deploy EAR to Oracle AS using maven?

Tags: oracle, deployment, maven-2, weblogic

Is there a way to remotely deploy an EAR after building it to Oracle AS? Remote deployment functionality exists for Eclipse, and I'm looking for something similar for maven2:

http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E14545_01/help/oracle.eclipse.tools.weblogic.doc/html/conFeatureOverview.html#remoteDep

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Verified on Oc4j 10

http://chadthedeveloper.blogspot.com/2008/05/automated-deployment-to-oc4j-in-maven2.html

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the [Weblogic Maven plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/weblogic-maven-plugin/)? The [weblogic:deploy](http://mojo.codehaus.org/weblogic-maven-plugin/deploy-mojo.html) goal seems to do exactly what you want. I've not used it myself so can't confirm if it actually works or not.

Update:
Found this [blog](http://blogs.steeplesoft.com/seam-and-jpa-hibernate-on-oc4j-1013/) that describes deploying to 10.1.3, though not using the weblogic plugin.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I would appreciate if someone could confirm whether this works also with Oracle AS 10.

Comment: I've not seen any evidence for or against, though it should be pretty quick to confirm it yourself. It has been tested with versions 8.1 SP 4-6 and 9.0 - 9.2 MP3. If the API has changed you should get a pretty clear error.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a complete answer your question; is's just a checklist for things to look up while solving this:

- what to do with generated sources, when to generate them?
- do you need custom information in META-INF?
- how to manage jars?

  - you can have them installed in an external repository, local repository, or specify them with system, on a project relative path, or a system absolute path
  - if specified with system, you can keep compile time jars in any location, and those that you want inside wars inside webapp/WEB-INF

If your project has a maven friendly architecture, then ok. Otherwise you can specify custom paths like this:

```
<packaging>ear</packaging>
<build>
    <finalName>ear-name</finalName>

    <!-- you can have only one source path-->
    <sourceDirectory>src-dir-path</sourceDirectory>

    <!-- you can have only one test path-->
    <testSourceDirectory>test-dir-path</testSourceDirectory>

    <!-- you can have several resource paths -->
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src-resources-path</directory>
            <excludes>
                <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
            </excludes>
        </resource>
    </resources>

    <!-- you can have several test resource paths -->
    <testResources>
        <testResource>
            <directory>test-resources-path</directory>
            <excludes>
                <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
            </excludes>
        </testResource>
    </testResources>
</build>
```

Other tips:

- study Eclipse generated ear, and maven generated ear, check for differences
- you can find missing jars with *mvn compile*, don't use an IDE for this, you want to make sure that maven has all the jars it needs
- you can have ant scripts inside maven, use maven-antrun-plugin, i can provide examples if requested